# Add button in sharepoint item display form to open edit form

Tags: form, display-form, designer

please help me to resolve my issue. For user experience i must add button in sharepoint display form that will open item for editing. I can add button with this script 
&nbsp
but i dont know how add action.

Comment: How you develop your form? CEWP you are using or any other plz define then I'll let you know. Plz go through Below link may be you got success.. 
 https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/1f307ff9-22e0-416e-8db3-f42d8b0e8968/open-edit-form-directly-when-list-item-is-clicked-in-sharepoint-list?forum=sharepointdevelopmentprevious

Answer (score 0):

Use below steps:

1. On display form get Item ID from url using query string parameters.
2. Add button in on page using CEWP.
3. On button click write a function and in this function redirect current page to edit form by creating link something like below:

   siteUrl/lists/listName/editform.aspx?ID=itemId;

Where `itemId` is the ID of item found from step 1.